# RPC style API, swagger and Play framework 2 (swagger-core)

Tags: playframework, rpc, playframework-2.1, swagger

I am implementing an RPC type API app. I am using Java on play framework.
I already used swagger modules to generate swagger documentation for simple rest APIs where each "URL" mapped to a different static function in my controllers. But here I need to map one URL and one static function to multiple Actions in the API docs.

The basic structure is quite classic

```
abstract class RPCActionRequest implements Serializable{
  public int actionCode; //this might be an enum too
  public RPCActionParam param;
}

interface RPCActionParam implements Serializable{
}

abstract class RPCAction {
  public int actionCode;
  public abstract RPCActionResult execute(RPCActionParam param);
}

interface RPCActionResult implements Serializable{
  public int responseCode; //sUCCESS, ERROR, FAIL, ... whatever errors my system needs to
                           //communicate to the client.
}
```

every single of the actions map to the same static function in my RPCController mapper as such in the routes file of play framework

/rpc/                  routes.RPCController.rpc()

How can I document all the actions, param classes and results classes using swagger and swagger-core doc generations? Is it possible to do with just the @Api* annotations of the swagger-play2 module?

refs:

-Swagger : https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/

-Swagger-core : https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core